# How to give constraints of two parameter optimization in Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, mathematica-online

In the lagrange multiplier method, the equations are :
f[x_,y_]:=x^2+y^2
g[x_,y_]:=6x+8y

The range of x and y values are 0<=x<=0.9, 0<=y<=10. How can I give the mentioned range of values in mathematical? when I give the following code, its keep running all the time without providing the solution.

`Solve[ D[f[x, y] - lambda g[x, y], {{x, y, lambda}}] == 0 && 0<=x<=0.9 && 0 <=y<=10,  {x, y}, lambda ]`

Comment: Try `Solve[D[x^2 + y^2 - lambda (6 x + 8 y), {{x, y, lambda}}] == 0 && 
   0 <= x <= 0.9 && 0 <= y <= 10 // Rationalize , {x, y, lambda}]`

Comment: Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Probably not, you have to group the three unknowns in one list `{x, y, lambda}`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, I am getting the same result when I group in the same list as well as in the different list. The above syntax is correct only. Thank you.

Comment: Hard to believe: Mathemativa v12.2 doesn't evaluate `Solve[D[f[x, y] - lambda g[x, y], {{x, y, lambda}}] == 0 && 
  0 <= x <= 0.9 && 0 <= y <= 10, {x, y}, lambda]` and gives a warning message `...lambda is not a valid domain...` .

Comment: yes, Correct. It is giving a warning and produces the value for ''x'' and ''y''. If you put x,y and lambda all in one list, it gives value for lambda also. But the value of x and y remains the same.